# Sending Parameters when opening mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my Controller I return the View for a specific model by

```
return View(model);
```

(Nothing magic there). Now this view contains a lot of Elements like different tabs. I want to send and receive a parameter to that view so I can display a specific tab depending on the parameter I send.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions in one. I will answer them one by one:

**Passing information to view**

One option is to use ViewBag. Second is to extend your model to contains information about which tab should be passed

**Passing information from client**

In action link you have to generate parameter to pass which View should be open. This parameter will be attached to query string so you can easy map it to input parameter for controller or read it from query string.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `ViewBag` or `ViewData`.

In your controller

```
ViewBag.test = "some text";
```

In your view

```
@ViewBag.test
```